# Is it possible to show markers from MySQL database with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, leaflet, markers

I'm interested if it's possible to show markers (latit, longit) from MySQL database with Javascript libraries like Leaflet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568965/get-data-from-mysql-database-to-use-in-javascript but better to mask (databasase connections) it using php http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: Thank you, is there some sample with markers maybe?

Answer (score 1):

yes, it's possible. As long you have the coordinate, then you can display either using OpenLayers or GMap.